# ufc champions by fighting style and weightclass graph display openframeworks c++

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I cant seem to get a graph in openframeworks to be displayed. I am trying to create a project where a txt file is inputted with data I'll show at the bottom to be displayed as a graph. Here is the file

```
Heavyweight - Wrestling - 9
Heavyweight - Kick Boxing - 6
Heavyweight - JiuJitsu - 4
Heavyweight - Boxing - 1
Light Heavyweight - JiuJitsu/Wrestling - 1
Light Heavyweight - Wrestling - 8
Light Heavyweight - Boxing - 1
Light Heavyweight - Kick Boxing - 2
Light Heavyweight - Karate - 1
Middleweight - Wrestling - 3
Middleweight - JiuJitsu - 5
Middleweight - Kick Boxing - 4
Middleweight - Karate - 1
Welterweight - Wrestling - 7
Welterweight - JiuJitsu - 5
Welterweight - Kick Boxing - 3
Welterweight - Boxing - 1
Welterweight - Karate - 1
Lightweight - Boxing - 1
Lightweight - Wrestling - 6
Lightweight - JiuJitsu - 4
Lightweight - Kick Boxing - 3
Featherweight - Kick Boxing - 4
Featherweight - Boxing - 1
Bantamweight - Wrestling/Kick Boxing - 1
Bantamweight - Kick Boxing - 1
Bantamweight - Wrestling/Boxing - 1
Flyweight - Wrestling - 2
Women's Featherweight - Kick Boxing - 2
Women's Bantamweight - Judo - 1
Women's Bantamweight - Boxing - 1
Women's Bantamweight - Wrestling - 2
Women's Flyweight - Wrestling - 1
Women's Flyweight - Kick Boxing - 1
Women's Strawweight - Wrestling - 1
Women's Strawweight - Kick Boxing - 1
Women's Strawweight - JiuJitsu/Kick Boxing - 1
Superweight - JiuJitsu/Wrestling - 1
Superweight - Wrestling - 1
```

I was able to execute the code but no display please help.

Comment: You're missing a [mcve].  [Edit] your question.

Comment: Not just missing a minimum example--completely missing any code of any kind.